# Phone number doesn't get validated javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm making a form and my validation function works, but completely ignores the phone number and allows it to be sent.

What I need to happen is that if the phone number doesnt contain exactly 10 numbers it gets rejected.

If I copy the exact code and put it in a seperate function:

```
<button onclick="CheckTelephone()">Click</button>


function CheckTelephone(){
var Telephone       = document.forms["OrderForm"]["Telefoon"]       .value.length;

if (Telefoon != 10){
    document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = "Telefoon nummer moet 10 cijfers bevatten.";
    setTimeout("ErrorClear()",5000);
    return false;}
}
```

But when I submit my form on the full code It allows any number to be sent: (all the way at the bottom)

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()" name="OrderForm">
<input type="submit" id="SubmitForm" name="SubmitForm" value="Plaats Bestelling">

// Form validation
function validate(){
// Variables
var TotalAmount     = document.getElementById('TotalAmount').innerHTML;

var Voornaam        = document.forms["OrderForm"]["Voornaam"]       .value;
var Achternaam      = document.forms["OrderForm"]["Achternaam"]     .value;
var Tussenvoegsel   = document.forms["OrderForm"]["Tussenvoegsel"]  .value;
var Email           = document.forms["OrderForm"]["Email"]          .value;
var EmailCheck      = document.forms["OrderForm"]["EmailCheck"]     .value;
var Telefoon        = document.forms["OrderForm"]["Telefoon"]       .value.length;

var PositionAt      = document.forms["OrderForm"]["Email"]          .value.indexOf('@');
var PositionDot     = document.forms["OrderForm"]["Email"]          .value.indexOf('.');

var NotNumbers          = /^[0-9]$/;

// Checks filled out or not ( || = OR(= Of))
if  (TotalAmount == 0 || TotalAmount <= 0){
    document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = "U heeft geen hoeveelheid oliebollen gekozen.";
    setTimeout("ErrorClear()",5000);
    return false;}
if  (  Voornaam   == null  || Voornaam   == "" 
    || Achternaam == null  || Achternaam == "" 
    || Email      == null  || Email      == "" 
    || EmailCheck == null  || EmailCheck == "" 
    || Telefoon   == null  || Telefoon   == ""){
    document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = "Niet alle verplichte velden zijn ingevuld.";
    setTimeout("ErrorClear()",5000);
    return false;}

// Checks if email adresses are the same or contains . and @
if  (PositionAt <1 || PositionDot-PositionAt <2 ){
    document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = "Het E-Mail adres bevat geen @ of . tekens.";
    setTimeout("ErrorClear()",5000);
    return false;}
if  (EmailCheck == Email ){return true;}else{
    document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = "De ingevoerde E-Mail adressen zijn niet gelijk.";
    setTimeout("ErrorClear()",5000);
    return false;}

// Checks if Telephone number contains 10 digits
if (Telefoon != 10){
    document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = "Telefoon nummer moet 10 cijfers bevatten.";
    setTimeout("ErrorClear()",5000);
    return false;}
// Somehow lets the phone number go trough even tough it's the exact same code


// If all correct
return true;
}
```

If anyone could tell me why this is happening or what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function call,

```
onclick="CheckTelefoon()" ....
```

and your Function definition,

```
function CheckTelephone(){ ....
```

Make the both unique to run your code without errors.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when adding the button really quickly, the first code works when I click on the button but when I actually try the exact same thing but on my full form it ignores it and simply sends the form off (second box of code)

Comment: The console doesn't give any errors, when I press submit it acts like I filled it in correctly and sends it off, where as if I mess up any of the other fields it will give me an error that tells me to correct that field.

Comment: edit: When I disable the emailcheck (the one above the telephone number check) It works, so I know where the problem is now but I cant find any problems with that part of the code

Comment: fixed it, the emailcheck sent it off because it returned true instantly if the two email adresses were the same, thanks for your help anyways